# ORM tool to create SQL tables

Tags: sql, database, orm

I need to create a database in *SQLite*, but I do not want to create the tables manually.

I already have the model of the data I need in the database, and what kind of relationship is each one (*many-many*, *one-many*, ...)

I'm wondering if there is a tool that allows me to do that?

**I just need the tool to generate the SQL code. Then I will take care of the queries manually using SQL**

I was thinking about placing the model in Django, and see what it generates, but there should be a tool not linked to a particular language that allows me to do that. Am I wrong?

Comment: as you don't say what platform you a are running on etc, there is no way anyone get give you a useful answser.

Comment: @Ian I don't know why it should be linked to a platform. I'm just looking for a tool that runs on Windows, where I 'tell' the application the relationships of my entities and it shows me the SQL code. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate have the ability to create a scheme from mapped classes. There is support for SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for dia (see "Tools that generates something from Dia diagrams" at http://projects.gnome.org/dia/links.html).

Also there is SQL::Translator and DBIx::* that allows reading an schema from YAML, Excel, and other sources, but these are Perl specific.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use Symfony + Doctrine framework. It can generate SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this module on CPAN: [Parse::Dia::SQL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse%3a%3aDia%3a%3aSQL)